# Simple IF with AND and numeric comparison not resolving correctly

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice-calc

I have the following formula:

> =IF(A14>=7 & A14<=18,"I","E")

It resolves to `I` (true) when A14 is 3 and it should resolve to `E` (false) as a matter of failing the left `if` criterium.

I am using `LibreOffice Calc` on `Ubuntu 14.4`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that, unlike in `Excel` the `LibreOffice` `AND` doesn't work with `&` but it has its own `AND` function:

> =IF(AND(A14>=7,A14<=18),"I","E")

ended up working out.